# R Create or Modify a dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am very new programming, and I am learning how to use dplyr, and I am wondering how to solve this problem:
I have this dataframe:

```
 countries <- c("USA","Canada","Denmark","Albania", "Turkey","France", "Italy")
 values <- c(1, 1, 3, 3,7,8,9)
 old_df <- data.frame(countries, values, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to modify the order into my dataset to obtain this:

```
countries <- c("USA , Canada","Denmark , Albania", "Turkey","France", "Italy")
values <- c(1,3,7,8,9)
new_df <- data.frame(countries, values, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Because I am using dyplr I think that the best way to solve my problem could be:

```
library(dplyr)  
new_df <- group_by(values) %>% 
                       transmute(countries = countries) %>% 
                ungroup
```

Thank you in advance for any clue about how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)

old_df %>%
  group_by(values) %>%
  summarise(countries = paste0(countries, collapse = ", "))

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
# values countries       
#    <dbl> <chr>           
# 1      1 USA, Canada     
# 2      3 Denmark, Albania
# 3      7 Turkey          
# 4      8 France          
# 5      9 Italy
```

The point here is that for each unique value in `values` you want to combine some of your rows, so you need to use `summarise` (i.e. you want to end up with one row per `values` value).

You can use `summarise(countries = paste0(sort(countries), collapse = ", "))` if you want to apply an alphabetical order when you combine countries.

Comment: Thank you! I did not consider the use of `summarise`.

Comment: If you want to create 1 row per value of your grouping variable then it will most likely be `summarise` :) The objective of this function is to "reduce multiple values down to a single value" as you can see here:`?summarise`